# How will taking a non technical position affect my long term technical future? Is it a bad idea?

Tags: career-development, job-change

Bit of background --

My long-term goals are to become a great software developer, with the primary idea of doing good for the world through that skill set. I have been teaching myself for about a year, and I have gotten a little bit of attention for a junior role, but am having a hard time gauging how close I am to being ready to get a job as a developer.

I am working a really stressful support desk job, which is not providing the technical growth I thought it would anymore. I do some basic technical work, but there is no code or development work at all. Work-life balance is pretty hard to set as expectations are vague. I have just started to apply for junior developer jobs and other roles that fit my goals.

I recently found an interesting opportunity in a non-technical role doing "Product training." It sounds like I would be a lot happier at this job, but I am a bit worried about taking this role, as it was made clear in the first interview that this is not a role where I will grow very much in a technical sense. It wouldn't prevent me from doing this, per se, but learning any coding skills here would be very forced.

How much will taking this role hurt my long term technical prospects? How much would it hurt my resume to only have a few months in a non-technical role, assuming I find a developer position in a few months? Would you take this job, given my goals?

Comment: You just want a job for a few months while looking for a software job? Might be better off keeping the job you have right now.

Answer (score 4):

Judging by your post, it seems that both jobs involve effectively none of the training and experience you want for your final goal, but you think only one of them would make you happy. Seems pretty clear to me.

As a bonus, if you're happy on the job you're more likely to spend your time off learning the skills you want for later jobs, so you'll be able to get more done that way. Personal projects on your resume are worth more than "I was too tired from that job to learn anything".

Answer (score -2):

I know this should be closed, as it's off-topic for the site, but I'm going to answer this anyway.

First, get over the idea of "Doing good for the world as a software developer."  The world needs people who want to help, but helping from behind a keyboard isn't really helping.

The best thing you can do as a software developer is to earn the best income possible, and use those funds to support Non-Government Organizations that do good in the world, or use the money to finance your own trips and efforts to help in the real world.

The real world needs help, but most of that help is with shovels and hammers.  After that, it's with books, beds, and medicine.  Earn a good living as a software developer doing whatever, and then go build houses with Habitat for Humanity.  Go help the Boy Scouts plant trees.  Get involved with the Rotarians and build clean water systems in Cambodia.  Send money to St. Jude's Children's hospital or to the Shriner's burn hospital.  THAT's how you help people being a software developer.

Yes, there are apps that help out disaster relief organizations.  Those are built by volunteers.  Do that, too.  However, building a house for a needy family or buying food for a starving child will do a lot more good than any application you build.

So - to answer your question:  Stop trying to merge your charity and your vocation.  Your vocation is your work.  What you do with the proceeds of your vocation is up to you, and it sounds like charity is where you'd want to put them.

Now go get the best job you can so you can do the most good.

Comment: The goal of helping the world with software, and donating to and/or direct help for various charity organisations, are not mutually exclusive. And, there is more to the world than the poorest. Sure, helping them is not bad, but there are enough things where doing it once mean both poor and not-so-poor can benefit from it.